find the area of the quadrilateral between the two coordinate axes and two intersecting lines,
Today someone asked me to solve a question related to calculating the area between the two coordinate axes and between two lines that have secant by knowing the coordinates of the points of intersection with the two coordinate axes, and the question included specific values and I do not usually care about this type of question, so I immediately tried to deal with the general situation
I've come up with a formula for the solution already, this is:


I know that there are many ways to attack the problem, such as the shoelace formula or the use of Euclidean geometry theorems or trigonometry, I am publishing this question to get the largest number of solutions, it is important to know that I am not interested in knowing the steps of the solution for a special case, but I am interested in deriving the formula $f$
Thank you all

Another solution using integration
Sorry for putting the solutions in the form of pictures, but I don't want to repeat writing again


First, the general equation of a line through two points $(x_0,y_0), (x_1,y_1)$ is:
$$\frac{y-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$$
We can apply this to the point $M$:
$$\frac{y_M-y_A}{y_D-y_A}=\frac{x_M-x_A}{x_D-x_A}\\
\frac{y_M-y_B}{y_C-y_B}=\frac{x_M-x_B}{x_C-x_B}
$$
Plugging in your values for these coordinates you can rewrite this as
$$y_M=-\frac da(x_M-a)=-\frac cb(x_M-b)$$
You can then get $x_M$ and $y_M$. Then $$Area(OCMA)=Area(\triangle OCM)+Area(\triangle OMA)=\frac12x_Mc+\frac12y_Ma$$

You are right. I've miscounted the minus signs. I've fixed it

Details of the solution proposed by @Andrei:


This is a third method using Menelaus' theorem:

